# OpenJDK crash logs on debian

Tags: linux, logging, debian, java

I have a java server application running on a debian machine which is crashing from time to time. I cannot find logs that would give me any information about the crash anywhere. There are no log files in the user home directory.

What could i do to gain information about the crash?

My system:

```
cat /etc/debian_version
8.6

java -version
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any hint appreciated.

Comment: Servers do not automatically have logs. Without knowing more about the name or nature of the server no one can help. Is this a server you wrote? If so, and you didn't do any logging in the code you wrote, there will be no logs.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It seems the OS killed my app, because now i have found this in /var/log/syslog: kernel: [33785288.294953] Out of memory in UB 122494: OOM killed process 26024 (java) score 0 vm:9600468kB, rss:3968468kB, swap:0kB

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OS killed my app, because now i have found this in /var/log/syslog:

```
kernel: [33785288.294953] Out of memory in UB 122494: OOM killed process 26024 (java) score 0 vm:9600468kB, rss:3968468kB, swap:0kB
```

– Martin